# Compiling a CSS Modules enabled library for NPM Publishing

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, babel-cli

I am creating a library which leverages CSS Modules (babel-plugin-react-css-modules) along with SASS. I dont want the consumers of my library to be worried about CSS Modules and SASS and have the appropriate rules setup in their bundler to enable this. Just like transpiling JS code through BABEL CLI, is there a way to acheive the same for CSS also wherein the compiler will go through all the SASS and CSS Modules enabled CSS files, compile them and create a compiled vanilla CSS file which can be used as it is.

Comment: What did you ultimately end up doing? I'm doing the same exact thing and would really appreciate hearing about your experience.